# Finding and looping through labels

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Running VS 2013 VB.net.

I have 3 labels on my aspx page labelled label1, label2 and label3.

I want to loop through each one in the code behind and assign values to them.

Here is my code

```
Dim X As Integer = 1

For Each obj In values

    Dim myLabel As Label
    myLabel = TryCast(Me.FindControl("Label" + X), Label)
    myLabel.Text = Math.Round(obj, 2)

    X = X + 1

Next
```

I know there is only 3 obj's so x will always be between 1 and 3.  What am I doing wrong as I get the following.

> Conversion from string "Label" to type 'Double' is not valid

IF I change ("label" + x) to ("label1") I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on the line below.

Comment: Are you concatenating? should not this be "Label" & X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to concatenate strings not to calculate, in VB.NET you use `&` instead of `+`(as opposed to C#). So this should work:

```
myLabel = TryCast(Me.FindControl("Label" & X), Label)
```

You should also set `Option Strict` to `On`, without exception. Then you first have to fix a lot of compiler errors, but it will help to write much more robust code. This wouldn't compile either:

```
myLabel.Text = Math.Round(obj, 2)
```

because a `Math.Round` returns a `Double` and `Label.Text` is a `String`. You just need to use `Math.Round(obj, 2).ToString()` to fix it.

Here's a different approach to get your labels using `Linq`:

```
Dim myLabels = From lbl In Me.Form.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
               Where lbl.ID.StartsWith("Label")
For Each lbl As Label In myLabels
    ' ... '
Next
```

Comment: I still get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' on the 'mylabel.text=' line.  Also mylabel is showing as nothing

Comment: @user2050577: maybe those labels are not at the top of the page but in another container control like a `GridView`, `UserControl` or you are using master-pages.

Comment: the labels are within a table.

Comment: @user2050577: What kind of table, a html-table or the ASP.NET `Table`-class or the `GridView`(which is also rendered as a table)?

Comment: theyre in a html table

Comment: @user2050577: that should work since `HtmlTable` does not implement `INamingContainer`(control-id's must be unuqiue in this table). But maybe this table is in another container control that implements it. Then you can't use `Me.FindControl` but you have to use `container.FindControl`. Maybe it helps if you show the relevant part of your aspx code.

Answer (score 0):

Also since your using `TryCast` check your variable before using it - it will be Nothing if it does not make the cast.

```
myLabel = TryCast(Me.FindControl("Label" & X.ToString), Label)
If myLabel IsNot Nothing Then
  'safe to use variable here
End If
```